# What are the tangents and asymptotes to $(x-1)(x+1)(x-3)$?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, derivatives

> What are the tangents and asymptotes to $(x-1)(x+1)(x-3)$?

The equation $$\frac{dy}{dx}=0$$ is not solvable so there are no tangents parallel to x-axis.
The function is increasing and it has no tangents at the origin.
The degree of the equation is $3$ and the $y=f(x)$ contains the highest degree of $x$, so it has no asymptote parallel to $x$.

I have problem finding asymptote parallel to $y$ axis and oblique asymptotes. For asymptote parallel to $y$ axis, we have to equate the coefficient of $y$ to zero, which is $1=0$ ?

What are oblique asymptotes?

Comment: It's true that a cubic does not have an asymptote, but are you sure about the lack of a point where $y'=0$?  What is the function $y'=f'(x)$ in this case?

Answer (score 1):

$f'(x) = 0$  is solvable:

$$f(x) = (x-1)(x+1)(x-3) = x^3 -3x^2 -x +3$$
$$f'(x) = 3x^2 -6x -1$$
$$f'(x) = 0  \implies x = 1 \pm \frac{2}{\sqrt{3}}$$
Try now.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

A cubic function with three real zeroes must cross the $x$-axis exactly three times.  What does this mean for the set of tangent lines to this cubic?